# GUI manipulation outside EDT in AWT not SWING

Tags: java, canvas, awt, event-dispatch-thread

The question is whether [`java.awt.Canvas.setBackground(Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)) may safely be called from the main thread (i.e. outside event dispatch thread) without risk of crashing.

**Background**

I am drafting an undergraduate lession about finite automata and seek a way to visualise their behaviour. I do not want to distract my students' attention from the subject by threading issues.
Java Swing requires precautions concerning threads when setting up and changing the GUI, see:

- [How to use Thread.sleep() and setBackground() to create flash effect in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905456/how-to-use-thread-sleep-and-setbackground-to-create-flash-effect-in-swing/11906107)
- [About the EDT (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901770/about-the-edt-java)

So Swing appears not to be an option at this stage. The above articles seem to be concerned about Swing rather than AWT. As to AWT, I read in

- [must all methods in AWT classes, i.e. non-Swing ones, be called in the EDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425588/must-all-methods-in-awt-classes-i-e-non-swing-ones-be-called-in-the-edt)

the promising statement that

> AWT Components were intended to be thread safe

**Question re-worded**

Is sufficient thread-safety documented in the AWT documentation so that I can rely on it for the Canvas class in all JREs?

**Demo code sample**

The AWT-related code I am talking about is as simple as the following colour-changer in `Colours.java`:

```
 import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.awt.Canvas;
 import java.awt.Color;

 /** Demonstrates Java AWT operated from main thread. */
 public class Colours {
    private static final Color[] colours = {
       Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE
    };
    public static void main ( final String[] arguments ) {
       final Frame frame = new Frame( "Colours" );
       final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
       frame.setSize( 320, 200 );
       frame.add( canvas );
       frame.setVisible( true );
       final ExitListener exitListener = new ExitListener();
       frame.addWindowListener( exitListener );
       int choice = 0;
       while ( ! exitListener.isExiting() ) {
          canvas.setBackground( colours[choice] );
          if ( ++choice >= colours.length ) {
             choice = 0;
          }
          try {
             Thread.sleep( 1000 );
          } catch ( final InterruptedException e ) {}
       }
    }
 }
```

and `ExitListener.java`:

```
 import java.awt.Window;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
 import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

 public class ExitListener implements WindowListener {

    private boolean isExiting = false;

    public boolean isExiting () {
       return isExiting;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated ( final WindowEvent e ) {}

    @Override
    public void windowClosed ( final WindowEvent e ) {}

    @Override
    public void windowClosing ( final WindowEvent e ) {
       isExiting = true;
       final Window window = e.getWindow();
       window.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated ( final WindowEvent e ) {}

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified ( final WindowEvent e ) {}

    @Override
    public void windowIconified ( final WindowEvent e ) {}

    @Override
    public void windowOpened ( final WindowEvent e ) {}
 }
```

N.B.: [java.awt.event.WindowAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) has not been used on purpose, because inheritance of state will be covered later in the course.

Comment: When reading my ExitListener code, I realise that the Java Virtual Memory Model will require isExiting to be a volatile field or a synchronized method (together with windowClosing) respectively.

Comment: *"The above articles seem to be concerned about Swing rather than AWT."* Don't be fooled. Everything that applies to Swing and the EDT applies equally to AWT. Dump AWT & use Swing - at least the experienced people will have used it within the last 7 years. And respect the EDT rules in both cases.